# Multiple setTimeouts in laterJS not sticking to schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, laterjs

I have an email database server in NodeJS which sends out scheduled emails in the below timescale.

```
Email 1: Immediately
Email 2: 3 days after email 1
Email 3: 7 days after email 1
```

However, when submitting multiple entries into the application, it throws off the scheduling, stepping through the setTimeouts in a random manner.

Here is the relevant code that schedules the emails

```js
server.post('/api/addUser', (req, res) => {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("heroku_XXXXXXXX");
    var myobj = { recruiter: req.body.recruiter, firstName: req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName, profile: req.body.profile, email: req.body.email, emailStep: 'Step 1', emailsCancelled: 'No', source: req.body.source, company: req.body.company, role: req.body.role };
    dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send('success');
      db.close();
      sendMail(myobj,req.body.emailOne, "Step 1");
      var sched = later.parse.recur().every(72).hour(),
        t = later.setTimeout(function() { sendMail(myobj,req.body.emailTwo, "Step 2"); }, sched);
      var sched2 = later.parse.recur().every(168).hour(),
          u = later.setTimeout(function() { sendMail(myobj,req.body.emailThree, "Step 3"); }, sched2);
    });
  });
});
```

The emails are firing fine and they are being passed through to SendGrid okay, it's just the scheduling that is messing up. I've tried removing LaterJS and just using setTimeouts but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on setTimeout for such long periods. I am not certain about the implementation details of setTimeout in node/v8, but whatever they do, computer clock will shift, virtual machine will also get paused/resumed.

Instead, define a task list, run a smaller function checking time every few minutes and running if there is any task necessary. You can also use crontab, etc. for calling an application to send emails. That way, you can also be sure that restarting this service will be fine.

Plus, I recommend cleaning up your code a little bit. Move things outside each function call by defining some variables maybe?